# How can I get The cell value of the gridControl when I click on a specific row?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to select the value of the firt cell when I click on a specific row in gridControl.

I tried this solution :

```
 int i=Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
```

But it seems it works only on gridView.Any Suggestins please?

Comment: try with `dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()`

Comment: `int i = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value);` or `bool IsValid = int.TryParse(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString(), out int value);` or (..).

Comment: @AleksaRistic  it gave me this Error :`GridControl' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedCells' and no 'SelectedCells' extension method that accepts a first argument of type 'GridControl' was found (is a using directive or an assembly reference missing? )  `

Comment: @Jimi I tried also your method but it game me the same error as the one above ...

Comment: It's not clear what control you are using. Is it the standard `DataGridView`,  devExpress `DataGrid` or something else? If the latter, see this [Access Grid Cells in Code](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/643/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Views/Grid-View/Cells#access)

Comment: I am using GridControl of DevExpress

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument753) help-article - to obtain the **specific row** cell value you can use the [ColumnView.GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowCellValuetopic) method as follows:

```
ColumnView view = (ColumnView)gridControl1.MainView;
string idStr = view.GetRowCellValue(2, "ID").ToString()
```

If you are using the **single-selection** mode(the [OptionsSelection.MultiSelect](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnViewOptionsSelection.MultiSelect.property) property is **false**) you can use the following API to obtain cell values of a focused row: 
 - [ColumnView.GetFocusedRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetFocusedRowCellValue.overloads);
 - [ColumnView.GetFocusedRowCellDisplayText](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetFocusedRowCellDisplayText.overloads).

These API utilized the handle of a **currently focused row** via the [FocusedRowHandle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedRowHandle.property) property:

```
int id = (int)view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Id");
```

To learn more, take a look at [Accessing Rows in Code. Row Handles](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3484/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Views/Grid-View/Rows#row_access) help article.

Comment: it gives me this error : `'GridControl' does not contain a definition for 'GetFocusedRowCellValue' and no 'GetFocusedRowCellValue' extension method that accepts a first argument of type 'GridControl' was found (is a using directive or an assembly reference missing? ) `

Comment: I have mentioned the GridVeiw object rather that GridControl object. You can obtain the GridView object from the GridControl using the following: `GridView gridView = gridControl1.MainView as GridView`